# Dynamically create tabs QTabWidget and fill tables QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt-designer, qtablewidget, qtabwidget

I am working with QtDesigner, I have a QTabWidget and inside each tab I have a QTableWidget, using a gridLayout to make the table full fit the tab.

I am filling the first tab/table like this:

```
self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(ncols)
self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(nrows)

myrows = [row.fetch_all_fields() for row in tab]
for i, row in enumerate(myrows):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(col))
                self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)
                QApplication.instance().processEvents()
```

This is working very good, the first time the user presses a button, this code is executed, and the table inside the first tab is filled.

But, the idea is that, each time the user presses the button, a new tab/table is created and filled with the requested data, the problem is, as many of you may have guessed, it works the first time, but after the first time, the second tab contains a second table which is not called `self.ui.tableWidget` anymore, it is called something else like, `self.ui.tableWidget_2` and then, of course, the code does not work anymore.

So the question is how to do that dynamically, I mean, each time a button is pressed, a new tab/table should be created, and the code above should be re-used every time to fill the new table created.

Would it be possible? I would appreciate any idea or suggestion about how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set up everything in Qt Designer, then your tab-widget will have a widget (page) for each tab, and each page will contain a table-widget.

The [QTabWidget.widget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#widget) method can access the widget (page) for each tab by index. And you can use [QObject.findChild](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChild) to get the table-widget the page contains:

```
    page = self.ui.tabWidget.widget(index)
    tablewidget = page.findChild(QTableWidget)
```

So this will allow you to access any table-widget by index, rather than having to know a specific attribute name.

Comment: Thanks!!, exactly was I was looking for, and looks so simple!!

Comment: Thank you very much! What a brilliantly simple approach!!! This was a real roadblock in my project! My program was to add as many tabs as user selections in a list and fill those tabs with tables and have data in them! Thank you very much! I'd buy you a coffee if I could.